# Implement Iterators Even When Not Needed? C++

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have a container called "ntuple" that is essentially a C array and length. It's main purpose is to be the argument of multi-dimensional math functions. As of now, it's really fast and utilizes several constructors of the form

```
ntuple(double x, double y, double z)
{
    size = 3;
    vec = new double[size];
    vec[0] = x;
    vec[1] = y;
    vec[2] = z;
}
```

And every time I work with a higher dimensional, yet known function, I just add a new constructor. I have on for an array as well:

```
ntuple(double* invec, long unsigned insizesize)
```

In order to make my code more compatible with regular c++ code, should I implement an ntuple iterator class? Nothing I've done has needed one and it seems like it will just slow everything down. But the more I read, the more vital it seems to use iterators for the sake of compatibility with standard C++ code.

I worry that when someone tries to work with my code, it won't mesh well with the standard techniques that they expect to use. But the purpose of my ntuple class is just to take arguments into functions.

Should I implement the iterators just as a precaution (if someone else will try to use the STL on it) at the cost of slowing my code?

Thanks.

Comment: A properly implemented iterator won't affect the speed of anything else.

Comment: Is there a reason why your `ntuple` isn't `std::vector<double>`? Is that reason any good?

Comment: @Yakk yes, to minimize the space that my argument takes up. This program solves large systems of equations and since, in math, the argument of a function doesn't change throughout the function, I don't need push_back or anything else.

Comment: @user2303321 In MSVC2012 on 32 bits, `sizeof(std::vector)` is 12 bytes.  Your class appears to be at least 8 bytes.  You are doing manual memory management because you don't want your function arguments to be 4 bytes larger?  The existence of `push_back` and all those other methods adds nothing to the size of an instance of `std::vector` nor does it impact the run-time cost of using it.  You can make the parameter a `std::vector<double> const&` and you have a non-mutable container of non-mutable `double`s that will be better written than your `ntuple` almost certainly...

Comment: @PeteBecker How is that so? Every time I create an ntuple, won't it also have to make space for the iterators it contains, and in those iterators, space for all the member functions?

Comment: @user2303321 no.  Member functions do not take up space in an instance.  And you wouldn't store an iterator in your class, you'd produce an iterator when asked.

Comment: @Yakk The arguments of my functions can be very large (when using the array constructor). Are you telling me that even in such a case, there is a 4 byte difference?

Comment: @user2303321: member functions certainly do not take up space in an object. But it's wonderful to see that you haven't even bothered to measure before deciding which solution is best, in what, according to you, is quite performance-sensitive code. Good to see the proudest traditions of computer science being upheld here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementing iterators for a wrapper around a C array is trivial -- just return pointers to the first, and one-past-the-last, element for `begin` and `end` respectively, and adding non-virtual methods to a POD class won't slow down much of anything.  Accessing the array via these methods won't be any slower than using array index lookups, and can be faster in some contexts.  And if you don't use them, your code won't run slower.

As an advantage, in C++11 if you have a `begin` and `end` method, `std::begin` and `std::end` will find it, and `for( auto x: container ) { /* code */ }` will work on your type.

As this seems to be an X/Y problem, I suspect one of your problems is that you shouldn't be using your `ntuple` class at all.  `std::vector<double>` is already a thin wrapper around a C-style array that is well written.  To pass it without the cost of copying it, `std::vector<double> const&`.

As a pedantic aside, the STL refers to the library from which the template component of `std` was derived.  It differs slightly from the `std` library in a few ways.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use vector but (if you really have lots of data in memory) be very careful to manage vector's memory. Then you will really have this 4 byte overhead (wasted for capacity).

- allways create vector with explicit size, or create empty and use resize()
- fill vector using indices (as you do vec[0] = ...)
- never use push_back - it can request (twice) more memory than needed

You can also enforce this rules with inheriting vector (though sometimes this practice is not recommended) like this

```
class ntuple: public std::vector<double> {
private:
    typedef std::vector<double> super;
    void push_back(double); // do not implement
    // also forbid pop_back()
public:
    ntuble(double a, double b) {
      resize(2);
      (*this)[0] = a;
      (*this)[1] = b;
    }
    ntuple(double* invec, long unsigned size)
      : super(invec, invec + size)
    {
    }
    // all your other convenient constructors here
};
```

iterators will still be accessible with begin() and end() methods